# Replace substring in text in current cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet. I want to look at the text in each cell, which is either two options separated by a slash, like this:

```
Yes / No
```

Or possibly two reasons and then an explanation separated by another slash, like this:

```
Yes / Yes / Reasons for the answer
```

And I want to delete everything after the first slash, **but** leave the second slash and everything thereafter in place, if it exists.

What's the best way to do this? I think I want to use `REGEXPREPLACE`, and I probably want something like this:

```
=REGEXPREPLACE($currentcell, "\/.*[\/|$]", "")
```

But two things:

1. I'm not too sure how to get the value of the current cell without creating a circular reference
2. I'm not sure how to create a regex for "either a second slash or the end of the string", trying `[\/|$]` but not sure if this is right.

UPDATE: (2) might be tricky. `REGEXPREPLACE` doesn't seem to do quite what I need. Nor does `REGEXEXTRACT`. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you need to convert:

```
Yes / No → Yes
Yes / Yes / Reasons for the answer → Yes / Reasons for the answer
No / Yes / Reasons for the answer → No / Reasons for the answer
```

Here's the formula that migth help:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CONCATENATE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".+(\/.+)\/.+|(\/.+)")),"")
```

The regex, used in this formula looks for either first slash and everithing up to second slash, or the only slash and leading symbols. `CONCATENATE` is used to combine the string, and `substitute` is used for example. `REGEXREPLACE` could also work:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,CONCATENATE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".+(\/.+)\/.+|(\/.+)")),"")
```

If this won't work, please give more examples on what result you want. Also possiply there are more elegant solutions.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you! The only issue is that it produces an error in empty cells - `Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value ".+(\/.+)\/.+|(\/.+)" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "".`. Any way around that?

Comment: Also, I can't use it in cell A1 - I get a circular dependency error. But there may be no way around that, I guess.

Comment: 1.  `REGEX` functions will return error when they deal with empty string, to get round this paste the formula into iferror: `iferror(function)`. 2. circular dependency error is common error for all functions in Google sheets, cell can't refference itself. 3. If you want, the formula could be converted into ArrayFormula, and it'll expand on the whole column automatically.

Comment: Very grateful for the help and education!

Answer (score 0):

You could also simplify it with the an "or" condition in your regex:

```
=CONCATENATE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(^.*\/).*\/(.*$)|(^.*)\/.*$"))
```

Note: You want the longer option to be the first condition it check otherwise the the shorter one will always be true.